# Array.concat() returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, concatenation

I'm creating a web application using React 16.10 and when I try adding an element to an empty array using `Array.concat()`, at first it returns an empty array and after the second try it returns the extended array.

The reasons why I'm not using `Array.push()`:

- it returns the lenght of the extended array
- ["Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable."](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

Here is the code:

```js
const [pizzas, setPizzas]= useState([]);

const addPizza = (type, size, dough, price) => {
    setPizzas(pizzas.concat([{type, size, dough, price}]));
    console.log(pizzas);
}
```

The `addPizza` function is triggered when the button is clicked. When I click it the first time, console returns `[]`, but when I click it the second time, it returns the extended array: `[{...}]`.

The weird thing is that when I try doing something similar in the browser's console, it works correctly:

```
const a = [];

a.concat({name: 'James'}); // returns [{name: 'James'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.concat()` doesn't modify an `Array`; it returns a new Array containing the concatenation. Thus, this line does set the pizzas *state* in the next render to an array with the new item:

```
setPizzas(pizzas.concat([{type, size, dough, price}]));
```

...because it sort of translates to this:

```
const newPizzas = pizzas.concat([{type, size, dough, price}]);
setPizzas(newPizzas);
```

...but the local `pizzas` variable you're logging is not modified. The next time `useState` is called, `pizzas` will have the new value, however.

Comment: set value is assigning in next useState call, how can i set value in real-time?

Comment: You would have to use `let` instead of `const` and assign to the variable in addition to doing set call. That is not the typical way that React apps are built, though. Normally you just let the change reflect in the next render and use things like `useEffect` to respond to state changes with procedural logic.

Answer (score 0):

setting state in React is asynchronous. When you call a setter obtained from `useState` the guarantee you have is that *in the future* the function will be called with the new updated state.

It does not update the existing reference (to `pizzas`) - rather it calls the function with the new one.

That's just how state works in react - presumably to create a pretense of immutability inside a render.